# How to monitor Spring object creation?

Tags: java, spring, mule

I have a Mule project using Spring beans.  I am curious if there is a way to monitor Spring as it creates objects.  I think I have a one or more Spring beans being created repeatedly rather than once.  Is there a way I can observe the project to see if this is true?

Comment: Add a log in the beans constructors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the  [InitializingBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) interface

```
public class MyBean implements InitializingBean {


   @Override
   void afterPropertiesSet() {
       // ....
   }
}
```

Or use the [@PostContruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotation on a method.

```
public class MyBean implements InitializingBean {


   @PostConstruct
   void aMethodToExecuteAfterTheBeanInit() {
       // ....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always query the Application Context at various points in your program.

```
private static void showSessionContext(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    String[] beanDefinitionNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();

    for (String bean : beanDefinitionNames) {
        System.out.println("Bean-------> : " + bean);
    }
}
```